# How to solve $x^2=49$ Algebraically for a $+7$ and $-7$ answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

By intuition it can be determined that $-7$ as well as $+7$ satisfy the condition $x^2=49$ but when I take square root both sides I get the equation $\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{49}$ which can only yield $+7$ due to the underoot.How do I solve algebraically for a $-7$ and $+7$ answer.

Comment: Difference of squares.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}\ne x $.  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.   So taking square roots of both sides results in $|x| =7$ which has two solutions $x=7$ or $x=-7$.  We generalize this result by stating $x^2 = k \implies x =\pm \sqrt {k} $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$x^2-49=(x+7)(x-7)=0$$ (difference of two squares) and one of the factors must be equal to zero. Alternatively just square root with $x=\pm 7$ (as in the quadratic formula)

Answer (score 3):

$$x^2=49$$ 
$$ \begin{cases}
\ y=x^2
\\ y=49
\end{cases}$$
[image]

Answer (score 2):

$x^2= 49\not \implies x=7$

$x^2=49\implies \sqrt {x^2} =7 \not \implies x=7$ because $\sqrt{x^2}\ne x$.

$\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$ which only equals $x $ if $x$ is nonnegative.  If $x $ is negative then $|x|=-x $ (which is *not* a negative number.  $-x $ is a *positive* number if $x $ is negative).

So $\sqrt {x^2}=49\implies |x|=7 \implies \pm x = 7 \implies x =\pm 7$.

Both roots accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

After taking root both the side you must get the equation:$$\sqrt {x^2}=\pm\sqrt{49}$$ $$x=\pm7$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does yield only $+7$. However, your LHS is not $x$, it is $|x|$, as $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. This is because it must be the positive root by definition. So,

$$\begin{align}x^2 &= 49\\\sqrt{x^2}&=\sqrt{49}\\|x|&=7\\
x&=\pm7\end{align}$$